# Write to SD card to android in Windows 10

Tags: sd-card, 7.1-nougat

Im trying to put some music on my SD card but i've left my micro sdcard reader at home. I do have my charger cable. I can see the files of the sd card on my laptop. But I can't write my music from my laptop to the SD card. Is there a way to enable write permissions of the SD card?

Thanks for thinking with me!

My phone is the Samsung Galaxy J5 2016 (Android 7.1.1)

Comment: Have you tried using a file explorer?

Answer (score 0):

It should just work. The SD card should be writeable by the MTP drivers installed on your PC.
Can you please upload a screenshot of the error that appears when you try to paste your music files? Do try creating a new folder and pasting inside it.